# ember init modal controller

Tags: ember.js, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog as a component, and I want to init a controller property with some value from the model (that changes every time I open the modal)

The thing is that the modal is hiding and showing, so `didInsertElement` is called only once.

All the solutions I see for it are saying to do it on `setupController` or any other route related methods, but I have no route. All I have is:

routes/application.js:

```
showModal: function(name, model) {
      this.render(name, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal',
        model: model
      });
    },
```

Comment: I wonder if you should disconnect the outlet(http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_disconnectOutlet) instead of hiding it when you close the modal, that way the didInsertElement on view will always be called when you open up the modal and in that hook you can set your controller properties.

Comment: actually that's what is happening... and I needed to add a view in order to bind a method to didInsertElement... if you want to write a complete answer I'll accept it

Comment: Oh so do you mean that you don't want to create a view for each modal(name)? Maybe I didn't understand your problem quite right. If that's the case then the given link might not be that helpful to you, but you can provide view name when calling this.render - more here http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render

Answer (score 0):

In the modal controller you can have an initializer member function like this. In this function you can update the fields based on model passed to the "rendered" modal template.

`initializer: Ember.computed('model', function() {
        var record = this.get('model');
        this.set('yourModalField', record.modalField);
    })`